# Como colocar tachado a una lista de tareas en Javascript con checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, lista

Hola y gracias por entrar a mi primer post de pregunta :D. Hace poco empece a practiar programación en javascript a medida que hago un curso de desarrollo web. Hice una lista de tareas simples con checkbox, pero me propuse intentar que tambien al darle click a cada checkbox esta emitiera la orden de tachar el contenido de al lado, se como hacer ambas cosas por separado, intente combinarlas pero no tuve resultados satisfactorios.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#mainbutton");

function tasklist() {
    let item = document.getElementById('MainInput').value;
    let text = document.createTextNode(item);
    let newTask = document.createElement("li");
    var checkboxmaker = document.createElement('input');
    checkboxmaker.type = "checkbox";
    checkboxmaker.name = "name";
    checkboxmaker.value = "value";
    checkboxmaker.id = "id"
    checkboxmaker.classList = "corrected"
    newTask.appendChild(text);
    newTask.appendChild(checkboxmaker);
    document.getElementById("MainUl").appendChild(newTask);
}


el.addEventListener("click", tasklist);

const itemList = document.querySelector("#item-1");

function markdone() {
    itemList.classList.toggle("donete")
}

itemList.addEventListener("click", markdone);
```

```css
    .corrected {
    margin: 15px;
}

.donete {
    background-color: skyblue;
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: max-content;
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="main.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS ToDoTask Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mainform">
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <input id="MainInput"/>
        <button id= "mainbutton" type="button">Add Task</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="MainUl">
        <li id="item-1">ExampleTachado1</li>
    </ul>
     <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y aqui estarian las partes de CSS y JS, como ven, en la primera parte del codigo en JS, tengo lo que es la lista basica con las checkbox, y en la segunda parte de codigo puse de fomr manual un ejemplo del tachado que busco agregar, lo que intento hacer es que cuando se de click en un checbox, haga el tachado como en el ejemplo manual que hice de forma parelala con el primer *LI* que aparece en la UL.

Agradezco cualquier respuesta o sugerencia, es el primer ejercio que hago por mi cuenta y estoy dispuesto a aprender al 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pruébalo así, a ver si te convence:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#mainbutton");

function tasklist() {
  let item = document.getElementById('MainInput').value;
  let text = document.createTextNode(item);
  let newTask = document.createElement("li");
  var checkboxmaker = document.createElement('input');
  checkboxmaker.type = "checkbox";
  checkboxmaker.name = "name";
  checkboxmaker.value = "value";
  checkboxmaker.id = "id"
  checkboxmaker.classList = "corrected"
  newTask.appendChild(text);
  newTask.appendChild(checkboxmaker);
  document.getElementById("MainUl").appendChild(newTask);
}

el.addEventListener("click", tasklist);

function markdone(e) {
  if (e.target.type == "checkbox") {
    e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle("donete")
  }
}

MainUl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  markdone(e)
})
```

```css
.corrected {
  margin: 15px;
}

.donete {
  background-color: skyblue;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: max-content;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <link rel=stylesheet href="main.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS ToDoTask Manager</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="mainform">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <input id="MainInput" />
    <button id="mainbutton" type="button">Add Task</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="MainUl">
  </ul>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Explicación de los cambios

1. He quitado el ejemplo que tenias puesto de demostración del #item1 tanto en el HTML como en el javascript
2. He puesto a la escucha al **padre** de los elementos generados dinámicamente, para luego filtrarlos correctamente dentro de la función **markdone**.  Es una técnica denominada por [delegación de eventos](https://www.google.com/search?q=delegaci%C3%B3n+de+eventos+javascript), pues todos los eventos (como click) son pasados de hijos a padres siempre, y de este modo, al ser elementos creados dinámicamente, no podemos referenciarlos durante la carga del documento incial, pero si que podemos hacer que cuando el evento llega al padre éste comprueba de donde viene mediante la propiedad [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) del evento, y si es de los elementos esperados (en este caso del tipo **checkbox**) hacemos la acción que deseamos sobre ellos, en este caso agregarle o quitarle una clase.

```
MainUl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  markdone(e)
})
```

3. Basándome en la explicación anterior he reescrito la función **markdone** para que quede de este modo:

```
    function markdone(e) {
      if (e.target.type == "checkbox") {
        e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle("donete")
      }
    }
```

donde he usado [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) para situarme en el padre del input marcado, que se corresponde con la línea completa, y allí le he aplicado/quitado la clase **donete**.

Comment: Muchas gracias, asi queda perfecto, solo he quitado la caracteristica CSS de "backgroud-color" que no me acabo de convencer el alcance que abarcaba tambien parte de la checbox. Para que solo quedase el "text-decortation" y se viese bien y he entendido claramente el procedimiento, te agradezco un monton :D

Sin embargo tengo una pequeña duda, por que es necesario colocar:

"MainUl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  markdone(e)
})"

para que funcione el codigo y no basta con un:

"MainUl.addEventListener("click", markdone(e))"

Te agradeceria un monton si me puedes explicar :D

Comment: No, no basta con eso, porque segun parece primero el evento (e) es recogido por **function** y es después cuando se le puede pasar a **markdown(e)**.  De la otra forma no funciona. En la página de [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) hay más información y sintaxis alternativas.

Comment: Si la respuesta ha cumplimentado tu pregunta recuerda aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y la pregunta no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias. Pulsa [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante aceptarlas cuando han sido útiles a la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo he entendido!! :D